Automate Chrome Extension using Selenium?
i try to autoamte a chrome-extension using the following code:
This is the chrome-extension:
https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/email-hunter/mbindhfolmpijhodmgkloeeppmkhpmhc
And this is the code i try:
import os, sys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import pyautogui

path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])) 
fnExtension = os.path.join(path, "EmailHunter.crx")
  
print(f"Checking Browser driver...")
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--log-level=3')  
options.add_extension(fnExtension)  
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1})    
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled') 
srv=Service()
driver = webdriver.Chrome (service=srv, options=options)    
waitWD = WebDriverWait (driver, 10)         

link = f"https://www.orf.at" 
driver.get (link)    

fnExtensionIcon = os.path.join(path, "IconExtension.png")  
img_location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(fnExtension, confidence=0.5)
image_location_point = pyautogui.center(img_location)
x, y = image_location_point
pyautogui.click(x, y)

But i only get this error:
(seleniumALL) C:\DEVNEU\Fiverr2024\ORDER\robalf\TRYuseExtension>python test.py           
Checking Browser driver...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\DEVNEU\Fiverr2024\ORDER\robalf\TRYuseExtension\test.py", line 29, in <module>
    img_location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(fnExtension, confidence=0.5)
  File "C:\DEVNEU\.venv\seleniumALL\Lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 172, in wrapper
    return wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\DEVNEU\.venv\seleniumALL\Lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 210, in locateOnScreen
    return pyscreeze.locateOnScreen(*args, **kwargs)
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\DEVNEU\.venv\seleniumALL\Lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 405, in locateOnScreen
    retVal = locate(image, screenshotIm, **kwargs)
  File "C:\DEVNEU\.venv\seleniumALL\Lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 383, in locate
    points = tuple(locateAll(needleImage, haystackImage, **kwargs))
  File "C:\DEVNEU\.venv\seleniumALL\Lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 231, in _locateAll_opencv
    needleImage = _load_cv2(needleImage, grayscale)
  File "C:\DEVNEU\.venv\seleniumALL\Lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 193, in _load_cv2
    raise IOError(
    ...<3 lines>...
    )
OSError: Failed to read C:\DEVNEU\Fiverr2024\ORDER\robalf\TRYuseExtension\EmailHunter.crx because file is missing, has improper permissions, or is an unsupported or invalid format

How can i automate this extensions using Selenium?
(make several clicks on Icon and then get the data out of the text-box which is showing the emails from the extension)

Firstly you should import this library:
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

Then, you can create an assignment called button. After, call the function. Like this:
 button = driver.find_element(By.ID, "button-id")  
 button.click() 

You can set it with your own code.

Thx a lot - can you share a code snippet how this shoul work?
I can´t find the button in the html-code - its located in the browser - not the html-code.
Thats why i tried it with pyautogui instead

Sorry - thats not working
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="button-id"]"}
(Session info: chrome=131.0.6778.205); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception

There may be several reasons for this:
Since the button is created as a result of the previous click, it may take time for Selenium to detect the new element. In this case you can add a wait using WebDriverWait
